# Why does my django server not run after changing BASE_DIR?

Tags: python, django

I am getting the following error in when I run the server after I changed `BASE_DIR`:

```
$ python manage.py run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\NAZIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\NAZIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\NAZIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 83, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\NAZIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 70, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\NAZIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 177, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\NAZIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\website\website\website\settings.py", line 72, in <module>
    'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')

Comment: Your BASE_DIR should be a `Path` object not a `str`. Import `Path` objects from `pathlib`.

Comment: Joining `str`s with `os.path` will do too of course, but those are only strings not Paths

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
MEDIA_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/social_website/uploads/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, *MEDIA_URL.strip("/").split("/"))
```